# Loop through HTML code with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to search through a HTML code from a Website and open the searches with the Internet Explorer only if there is a result.
I tried to change the attached Code for my needs but I faild.

This is the Website where I want to search through.

https://www.boersen-zeitung.de/index.php?li=310&subm=suche&bzpro_suche=vw&bzpro_zeitraum=1%20Woche&page_number=1#jump

```
Sub SearchBot()

    'dimension (declare or set aside memory for) our variables
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer 'special object variable representing the IE browser
    Dim aEle As HTMLLinkElement 'special object variable for an <a> (link) element
    Dim y As Integer 'integer variable we'll use as a counter
    Dim result As String 'string variable that will hold our result link

    'initiating a new instance of Internet Explorer and asigning it to objIE
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

    'make IE browser visible (False would allow IE to run in the background)
    objIE.Visible = True

    'navigate IE to this web page (a pretty neat search engine really)
    objIE.navigate "https://duckduckgo.com"

    'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    'in the search box put cell "A2" value, the word "in" and cell "C1" value
    objIE.document.getElementById("search_form_input_homepage").Value = _
      Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value & " in " & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").Value

    'click the 'go' button
    objIE.document.getElementById("search_button_homepage").Click

    'wait again for the browser
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    'the first search result will go in row 2
    y = 2

    'for each <a> element in the collection of objects with class of 'result__a'...
    For Each aEle In objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("result__a")

        '...get the href link and print it to the sheet in col C, row y
        result = aEle
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & y).Value = result

        '...get the text within the element and print it to the sheet in col D
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & y).Value = aEle.innerText
        Debug.Print aEle.innerText

        'is it a yellowpages link?
        If InStr(result, "yellowpages.com") > 0 Or InStr(result, "yp.com") > 0 Then
            'make the result red
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & y).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            'place a 1 to the left
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & y).Value = 1
        End If

        'increment our row counter, so the next result goes below
        y = y + 1

    'repeat times the # of ele's we have in the collection
    Next

    'add up the yellowpages listings
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value = _
      Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B100"))

    'close the browser
    objIE.Quit

'exit our SearchBot subroutine
End Sub
```

In column A is my List for the Search Loop, the searching date should could be entered in column B

[image]

This is how I tried it.

[image]

Comment: How does the code fail? Do you get an error? If so, what error at what line? Does it work, just not return the expected results?

Comment: I attached another picture. It doesnt return any results sad wise.

Comment: I've just completed a web scraping exercise.  I use `While oHtml.readyState <> "complete"`to wait for a web page.  Full source at http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.co.uk/2018/01/vba-mshtml-webscraping-looking-for-new.html

Comment: boersen-zeitung.de or https://duckduckgo.com ?, your artefacts now mismatch.(src vs screenshot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some progress here is my code so far.  It gets results!  When scraping, you need to use querySelector if selecting by class name (class name is not the same as id).

```
Option Explicit


'See this http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.co.uk/2018/01/vba-mshtml-webscraping-looking-for-new.html

Sub SearchBot()

    'dimension (declare or set aside memory for) our variables
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer 'special object variable representing the IE browser
    Dim aEle As HTMLLinkElement 'special object variable for an <a> (link) element
    Dim y As Integer 'integer variable we'll use as a counter
    Dim result As String 'string variable that will hold our result link

    'initiating a new instance of Internet Explorer and asigning it to objIE
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

    'make IE browser visible (False would allow IE to run in the background)
    objIE.Visible = True

    'navigate IE to this web page (a pretty neat search engine really)
    objIE.navigate "https://www.boersen-zeitung.de/index.php?li=310&subm=suche"
    'objIE.navigate "https://duckduckgo.com"

    'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    Dim vCarManufacturer As Variant
    vCarManufacturer = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").value

    vCarManufacturer = "Daimler" 'overriden

    Dim vSearchURL As Variant
    vSearchURL = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").value
    vSearchURL = "" 'overriden

    Debug.Assert Not objIE.document Is Nothing

    Dim htmlSuche As Object
    Set htmlSuche = objIE.document.querySelector("input.suche_unternehmen")
    Debug.Assert Not htmlSuche Is Nothing

    'in the search box put cell "A2" value, the word "in" and cell "C1" value
    htmlSuche.value = _
      vCarManufacturer '& " in " & vSearchURL

    'click the 'go' button
    'objIE.document.getElementById("search_button_homepage").Click
    objIE.document.querySelector("input.suche_button21").Click

    'wait again for the browser
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    'the first search result will go in row 2
    y = 2

    'for each <a> element in the collection of objects with class of 'result__a'...

    Dim objResults As Object
    Set objResults = objIE.document.querySelectorAll("a.ue_fl_l")


    For Each aEle In objResults ' objIE.document.querysselec("result__a")

        '...get the href link and print it to the sheet in col C, row y
        Dim anchorResult As MSHTML.IHTMLAnchorElement
        Set anchorResult = aEle

        result = aEle
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & y).value = anchorResult.href ' result

        '...get the text within the element and print it to the sheet in col D
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & y).value = anchorResult.innerText
        Debug.Print aEle.innerText

        'is it a yellowpages link?
        If InStr(result, "yellowpages.com") > 0 Or InStr(result, "yp.com") > 0 Then
            'make the result red
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & y).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            'place a 1 to the left
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & y).value = 1
        End If

        'increment our row counter, so the next result goes below
        y = y + 1

    'repeat times the # of ele's we have in the collection
    Next

    'add up the yellowpages listings
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").value = _
      Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B100"))

    'close the browser
    objIE.Quit

'exit our SearchBot subroutine
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, it gets me the results!